# Using XCTest in non-Test Target

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xctest

I'm writing a reusable framework around XCTest for UI testing of several of our projects. For this I created a Cocoa Touch Framework project that I want to share via pods.

Is it possible to include XCTest into such a project (without extra test targets)? I'm getting errors that the XCTest module cannot be found even though I've linked `XCTest.framework` in the build phases.

Comment: See the answer here for an alternative method not involving Pods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147582/how-to-link-xctest-dependency-to-production-main-target

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add `$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` into `Framework Search Paths` which in the Build Settings of your framework target. Basically, you don't have to link your framework against `XCTest.framework`.

Also, if you're going to share the framework via pods you can add following code to your podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...
  s.weak_framework = "XCTest"
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) "$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks"',
  }
  ...
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: How import files in XCUITest Target from such pod?

Comment: This could be improved slightly by using the more specific DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR as the value. It resolves to the same dir as $(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks

Comment: As of Xcode 9, `DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR` no longer resolves to a sub-path of `PLATFORM_DIR` – hence `$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` is the correct search path now.